# How to convert the value get from Temperature Sensor?

Tags: c, sensors, i2c

I am working on ST `Temperature sensor( hts221 )` , I use `I2C` command communication with sensor.

I see from the document like the following text.

**`enter code here Temperature data are expressed as TEMP_OUT_H & TEMP_OUT_L as 2’s complement numbers.`**

And the following picture is the description from document.
[image]

And the `Temperature data` read from the sensor is like the following

```
TEMP_OUT_L is 0xA8
TEMP_OUT_H is 0xFF
```

**How to convert the value of TEMP_OUT_L and TEMP_OUT_H to the Temperature data ?**

Thanks in advance ?

Comment: What have you tried? If you have the 2 bytes from I2C, you have already done the hard part. Rest is a simple bit shift and OR-operation.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I don't think direct pointer dereference works. OP mentions that he's reading over I2C.

Comment: @user694733 Ah, missed that.

Comment: I hope there are more details... If not a glass of water with ice is at 0 Celsius or 32 Fahrenheit, what are your values.?

Answer (score 2):

By concatenating the bits in the two values, to form a single 16-bit value:

```
const temp_h = i2c_read_byte(TEMP_OUT_H);
const temp_l = i2c_read_byte(TEMP_OUT_L);
const uint16_t temp = (temp_h << 8) | temp_l;
```

This just assumes you have a function `uint8_t i2c_read_byte(uint8_t address);` that can be used to read out the two registers.

Of course, the next step would be to convert this raw binary number into an actual temperature in some proper unit (like degrees Celsius, or Kelvin). To do that, you need more information from the data sheet.

Comment: still, what's the scale? I feel like that should be documented somewhere. Is that vendor-specific?

Answer (score 2):

On page 6 of the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00116291.pdf) it says:

```
Temperature sensitivity 0.016 °C/LSB
```

So here's what you need to do:

```
#define TEMP_SENSITIVITY 0.016f
#define TEMP_OFFSET      ???    /* Get this value from the datasheet. */

unsigned char tempOutH;
unsigned char tempOutL;

/* Here you get the values for tempOutH and tempOutL. */

uint16_t tempData = (tempOutH << 8) | tempOutL;
float    temp     = (tempData * TEMP_SENSITIVITY) + TEMP_OFFSET;
```

So what you do is concatenate the two 8-bit high and low values. This gives you a single 16-bit value. Then you convert/scale that number between 0 and 65535 to the real temperature value.

I assumed that there must be an offset specified in the datasheet, because otherwise the temperature can only positive: between `0.0` and `65363 * 0.016`. This offset will be a negative value. I leave it up to you to find this offset.

Comment: Also, on page 25 of the data sheet (http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00116291.pdf) it flat out shows a worked out example using linear interpolation (y=mx+b) approach to converting the digital value to a temperature. Between this and the answer provided above, you have all the information you could need.

Comment: Sorry...I am new to this , I have see the page 25 in data sheet. But I still understand how to converting the value to a temperature...

Comment: @Martin I have not time to sort this out fully for you. I'd suggest you read the data sheet very carefully (multiple times if needed) it should all be in there. HTH

Answer (score 0):

`0xFF` part of `0xFFA8` seems suspicious for me, probably the device is configured to work in 8-bit mode (if it's even possible) , on the page 24 of the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00116291.pdf) it's said

> T0 and T1 are the actual calibration temperature values multiplied by
>   8.

So `0xA8` divided by 8 gives: 31.25 - isn't it temperature around you currently?

Comment: Sorry...I didn't understand. How you convert the 0xA8 to 31.25 ?

Comment: simply divide 250(0xa8) by 8, so 250/8=31.25